PostgreSQL: pg_dump fails to correctly pg_restore due to missing or erroneous custom function, but present in dump
I am running PostgreSQL 13.15 in a local docker container, with matching pg_dump/pg_restore versions. When dumping and restoring the database, one of the custom functions that was previously present appears to be missing when it comes to create the table. The table of interest is skipped during its COPY command. After database restore, the same function with the same input can be run successfully without issue.
I've trimmed down the plaintext pg_dump to the minimal reproducible example.
Here is the error that occurs during restore:
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
COMMENT
WARNING:  Value: Equipment
WARNING:  TYPE: text
ERROR:  function try_cast_jsonb(text) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT try_cast_jsonb(raw_text)
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT try_cast_jsonb(raw_text)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function public.content_aware_tsvector(regconfig,text[],character) line 18 at assignment
COPY searchable_items, line 1: "84      name    {}      {}      {Equipment}     A       app_user"

Here is the function execution after restore is complete within the psql shell:
mydb=# SELECT try_cast_jsonb('Equipment');
 try_cast_jsonb 
----------------

The function returns null if the string cannot be cast to jsonb.
The database dump was performed with the following command:
pg_dump --host localhost --port 1487 --dbname mydb --clean --if-exists > backuptest.sql

The restore was performed as follows into a clean database:
pg_restore --host localhost --port 1487 --dbname mydb --clean --if-exists --no-owner backuptest.sql

This occurs both in the plain and c formats.
Here is the pg_dump in plaintext:
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 13.15 (Debian 13.15-1.pgdg120+1)
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 13.15 (Debian 13.15-1.pgdg120+1)

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

-- DROP ALL CONSTRAINTS, INDEXES, FUNCTIONS, EXTENSIONS if existing
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.try_cast_jsonb(_text text);

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.content_aware_tsvector(_lang text, _raw_text text, _tsweight character);
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.content_aware_tsvector(_lang regconfig, _raw_text_arr text[], _tsweight character);
DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS pg_trgm;
DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS btree_gist;
--
-- Name: btree_gist; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist WITH SCHEMA public;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION btree_gist; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION btree_gist IS 'support for indexing common datatypes in GiST';


--
-- Name: pg_trgm; Type: EXTENSION; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm WITH SCHEMA public;


--
-- Name: EXTENSION pg_trgm; Type: COMMENT; Schema: -; Owner: 
--

COMMENT ON EXTENSION pg_trgm IS 'text similarity measurement and index searching based on trigrams';


--
-- Name: try_cast_jsonb(text); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: public; Owner: app_user
--

CREATE FUNCTION public.try_cast_jsonb(_text text) RETURNS jsonb
    LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE
    AS $$
        DECLARE
            trimmed_text text;
            casted_json jsonb;
        BEGIN
            -- Remove leading whitespace
            trimmed_text := ltrim(_text);

            -- Check if the string doesn't start with '{' or '['
            IF NOT (left(trimmed_text, 1) = '{' OR left(trimmed_text, 1) = '[') THEN
                RETURN NULL;
            END IF;

            BEGIN
                SELECT trimmed_text::jsonb INTO casted_json;
            EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
                RETURN NULL;
        END;

        RETURN casted_json;
        END;
    $$;


ALTER FUNCTION public.try_cast_jsonb(_text text) OWNER TO app_user;


--
-- Name: content_aware_tsvector(regconfig, text[], character); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: public; Owner: app_user
--

CREATE FUNCTION public.content_aware_tsvector(_lang regconfig, _raw_text_arr text[], _tsweight character DEFAULT NULL::bpchar) RETURNS tsvector
    LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
    AS $_$
        DECLARE
            vec tsvector;
            i integer;
            raw_text text;
            json_text jsonb;
            debug text;
        BEGIN
            vec := '';

            FOR i IN array_lower(_raw_text_arr, 1) .. array_upper(_raw_text_arr, 1) LOOP

                raw_text := COALESCE(_raw_text_arr[i], '');

                RAISE WARNING 'Value: %', raw_text;
                SELECT pg_typeof(raw_text) INTO debug; 
                RAISE WARNING 'TYPE: %', debug;
                json_text := try_cast_jsonb(raw_text);

                IF json_text IS NOT NULL THEN
                    -- JSON aware tsvector only indexes contents and not structure.
                    vec := vec || jsonb_to_tsvector(_lang, json_text, '["string", "numeric", "boolean"]'::jsonb);
                ELSEIF raw_text ~ '^[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}$' THEN
                    -- Makes UUIDs a single element in the index for only exact matches.
                    vec := vec || array_to_tsvector(ARRAY[raw_text]);
                ELSE
                    vec := vec || to_tsvector(_lang, raw_text);
                END IF;

            END LOOP;

            IF _tsweight IS NOT NULL THEN
                RETURN setweight(vec, _tsweight::"char");
            END IF;

            RETURN vec;
        END;
    $_$;


ALTER FUNCTION public.content_aware_tsvector(_lang regconfig, _raw_text_arr text[], _tsweight character) OWNER TO app_user;

--
-- Name: content_aware_tsvector(text, text, character); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: public; Owner: app_user
--

CREATE FUNCTION public.content_aware_tsvector(_lang text, _raw_text text, _tsweight character DEFAULT NULL::bpchar) RETURNS tsvector
    LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
    AS $$
            DECLARE
                raw_json json;
                vec tsvector;
            BEGIN
                BEGIN
                    raw_json = _raw_text::json;
                EXCEPTION
                    WHEN others THEN
                        raw_json = NULL;
                END;

                vec = (
                    CASE
                        WHEN raw_json IS NOT NULL THEN json_to_tsvector(_lang::regconfig, raw_json, '["string", "numeric", "boolean"]')
                        ELSE to_tsvector(_lang::regconfig, _raw_text)
                    END
                );

                IF _tsweight IS NOT NULL THEN
                    RETURN setweight(vec, _tsweight::"char");
                ELSE
                    RETURN vec;
                END IF;

            END;
        $$;


ALTER FUNCTION public.content_aware_tsvector(_lang text, _raw_text text, _tsweight character) OWNER TO app_user;



SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_table_access_method = heap;

--
-- Name: searchable_items; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: app_user
--

CREATE TABLE public.searchable_items (
    item_id integer NOT NULL,
    item_type text NOT NULL,
    pk_meta jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb NOT NULL,
    meta jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb NOT NULL,
    raw_text text[] NOT NULL,
    tsweight character(1) DEFAULT NULL::bpchar,
    tenant character varying DEFAULT CURRENT_USER NOT NULL,
    var_id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((((meta || pk_meta) ->> 'resource_var_id'::text))::integer) STORED,
    val_id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((((meta || pk_meta) ->> 'resource_val_id'::text))::integer) STORED,
    search_tsv_english tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (public.content_aware_tsvector('english'::regconfig, raw_text, tsweight)) STORED
);


ALTER TABLE public.searchable_items OWNER TO app_user;

--
-- Name: TABLE searchable_items; Type: COMMENT; Schema: public; Owner: app_user
--

COMMENT ON TABLE public.searchable_items IS 'Table for optimizing text based search';

--
-- Data for Name: searchable_items; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: app_user
--

COPY public.searchable_items (item_id, item_type, pk_meta, meta, raw_text, tsweight, tenant) FROM stdin;
84  name    {}  {}  {Equipment} A   app_user
84  description {}  {}  {"core resource class for the scheduling of equipment"} C   app_user


--
-- Name: searchable_items searchable_items_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: app_user
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.searchable_items
    ADD CONSTRAINT searchable_items_pkey PRIMARY KEY (item_id, item_type, pk_meta);


--
-- Name: trgm_search_idx; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: app_user
--

CREATE INDEX trgm_search_idx ON public.searchable_items USING gin (((array_to_tsvector(array_remove(raw_text, NULL::text)))::text) public.gin_trgm_ops);



--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--

What am I missing?  What can cause a pg_dump to fail when restored into the same PostgreSQL and psql tool versions?
The table that is failing to restore is as follows (also embedded in the dump above):
CREATE TABLE public.searchable_items (
    item_id integer NOT NULL,
    item_type text NOT NULL,
    pk_meta jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb NOT NULL,
    meta jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb NOT NULL,
    raw_text text[] NOT NULL,
    tsweight character(1) DEFAULT NULL::bpchar,
    tenant character varying DEFAULT CURRENT_USER NOT NULL,
    var_id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((((meta || pk_meta) ->> 'resource_var_id'::text))::integer) STORED,
    val_id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((((meta || pk_meta) ->> 'resource_val_id'::text))::integer) STORED,
    search_tsv_english tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (public.content_aware_tsvector('english'::regconfig, raw_text, tsweight)) STORED
);

The search_tsv_english calculated column that is derived from the raw_text and tsweight columns causes the failure. This custom function should be defined before the COPY command to restore the table is executed, but the error reports that the function is either not present, or there is an argument type mismatch.
Executing the COPY command manually after restore, runs without issue - as if the function was not persisted before the COPY command.

The preamble of your dump file contains this line:
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);

It resets the contents of the database object search path to an empty string for the duration of the session.
Further down in the dump you create the function public.try_cast_jsonb(), then attempt to call it in another function, public.content_aware_tsvector(), like so:
  json_text := try_cast_jsonb(raw_text);

This fails, because the schema public is not in search_path anymore and is no longer used to resolve unqualified object names. In other words, public.try_cast_jsonb() exists, but PostgreSQL was explicitly told not to look in public.
Resetting search_path for dump and restore is a security precaution, for the reasons explained in this PostgreSQL Wiki article.
For an immediate resolution, use the fully qualified name when calling the function:
  json_text := public.try_cast_jsonb(raw_text);

However, in addition to that, you should really avoid creating user objects in the public schema, for the reasons explained in the article referenced above. If necessary, public objects should be maintained by the superuser or another trusted role, and even then programmatic references to such objects should be explicit. search_path exists mostly to reduce the typing burden on users of interactive sessions
Beginning with PostgreSQL 15, users are no longer able to create objects in the public schema by default, enforcing this best practice.

Thanks a lot for your help on this one.  We were able to resolve the potential problem here by detecting and installing into the schema for the initializing user.
